# Doubt with matrix associated to a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a doubt about this.

My linear transformation is: $T:M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$
defined by $T(A)=BA$ With $B \in {M_{2}(\mathbb{R})}$

If i have this:

$\ T(\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0})=\pmatrix{a&0\\c&0}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0})=\pmatrix{0&a\\0&c}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0})=\pmatrix{b&d\\0&0}$

$\ T(\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1})=\pmatrix{0&b\\0&d}$

What would be the matrix associated with this linear transformation?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the basis. If we take the basis you have, i.e. $e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and so on, then the linear map sends $e_1 \mapsto ae_1 + be_3$ and so on, so matrix is
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & c & 0 \\
0 & a & 0 & c \\
b & d & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 & d
\end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: The result would be nicer if you pile up the colums instead of "piling up" the lines.

Comment: I don't think it really makes a difference either way. I just wrote it in the same order as the OP.

Comment: In fact, you are right...